# NgRx Effects infinite loop

Tags: angular, observable, ngrx, ngrx-effects

**I know that this question has been asked a million times on SO**. But I need help. I do realise I must be missing something crucial here. But I'm not seeing it.

Below code triggers an infinite loop. REMOVE_PROJECT is being dispatched only once. REMOVE_PROJECT_SUCCESS is being triggered infinitely. 'removed' is being logged infinitely. I have no idea why.

All Actions have unique types. `dispatch: false` is enabled for REMOVE_PROJECT_SUCCESS.

**Actions:**

```
export const REMOVE_PROJECT = createAction(
    '[Project] Remove Project',
    props<{ id: string }>()
);

export const REMOVE_PROJECT_SUCCESS = createAction(
    '[Project] Remove Project Success',
);
```

**Effects:**

```
@Effect()
removeProject$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ProjectActions.REMOVE_PROJECT),
    switchMap(props =>
        this.projects.removeProject(props.id).pipe(
           map(() => ({ type: '[Project] Remove Project Success'}),
        // have also tried
        // map(() => ProjectActions.REMOVE_PROJECT_SUCCESS())
        )
    ))
))


@Effect({ dispatch: false })
removeProjectSuccess$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ProjectActions.REMOVE_PROJECT_SUCCESS),
    tap(() => console.log('removed')),
))
```

**Delete function:**

```
removeProject(projectId): Observable<void> {
    return from(this.db.doc('projects/' + projectId).ref.delete());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're using the `@Effect()` decorator with `createEffect()`. They both do the same thing under the hood, likely triggering the infinite loop. Remove EITHER the `@Effect()` annotations (recommended) or `createEffect()` (I'd leave this one).

To be more specific, the `createEffect()` also takes `{dispatch: false}` as the second argument (after your observable pipe). Since you don't include this option for the second one, it just re-dispatches the actions you filtered with `ofType`, thereby firing the same actions over and over in the infinite loop you're experiencing.

Here's what the second effect should look like if you want to not dispatch:

```
removeProjectSuccess$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ProjectActions.REMOVE_PROJECT_SUCCESS),
    tap(() => console.log('removed')),
), { dispatch: false })
```

Under the hood, both the decorator and the function add annotations to the injectable class that the `EffectsModule` consumes. In this scenario, it makes an effect that will not dispatch, and a second one that dispatches by default. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Can't believe I hadn't noticed I was combining practices from different versions of NgRx. I feel so stupid :-( Thank you.